# Should right angles at pads be avoided in traces on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I have been told that traces shouldn't bend at 90 degrees or less, because electrons get trapped in those angles. Does the same also hold for when traces meet at pads?

[image: Example]

Is the left pad in C2 troublesome?

Comment: Electrons don't get trapped. PCB etching is done using chemicals which can get trapped in those corners and eat away a thin trace. However I am not sure whether we still need to worry about such things.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack So, it shouldn't make a difference if it is at a pad. Am I correct?

Comment: I've designed tons of boards and I've never had an issue with this. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Your coming straight in on one trace and the other is 45 degrees or more per corner, so you are doing just fine. Even with GHZ digital or RF there are programs like Saturn PCB Toolkit (free) and Orcad has Spectra (very expensive) to do finely detailed trace layout and pad stacks.

Comment: There is a very slight "trapping" of electrons and also sharp corners do "radiate." However, it's not usually important. Electrons trap in corners just sufficient to force the currents around the bend. But even for fairly large currents it doesn't take a lot of electrons to cause the current to take the bend. I wouldn't usually worry too much about it. But frequency does matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acute angle on a pad or a via](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414141/acute-angle-on-a-pad-or-a-via)

Comment: Depends on the frequency characteristics you desire, for your stuff (which doesn't look like its impedance controlled), it doesn't matter.